# why my Firebase uid does not show on my Stripe Dashboard?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

This is my index.js andhe functions are deployed in the Firebase Console as shown below:-
[image]

```
     const functions = require('firebase-functions');
   const admin = require('firebase-admin')
    const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_51HmAsMFzRM1fSBZ2CkBBjW5a3sEpxEQLGT7OkGxa8BZMMfgzT1Jeqs7dq63AlPRLIJmzHFC0HHAmKHDazcpriuh9001IWIVmw1');

  admin.initializeApp()

  const db = admin.firestore()
  const storage = admin.storage().bucket()
  const auth = admin.auth()

   exports.createStripeUser = functions.https.onCall( async (data, context) => {

    const email = data.email
    const uid = context.auth.uid

        if (uid === null) {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Illegal access attempt')
      }

     return stripe.customers.create({
    email: email,
     })
      .then(customer => {
      return customer["id"]
    })
    .then( customerId => {
     admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid).set(
      {
     stripeId: customerId,
     email: email,
      id: uid
      }
     )
    })
   .catch( err => {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Unable to create Stripe customer')
   })
  })

   exports.createEphemeralKey = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

   const customerId = data.customer_id;
   const stripeVersion = data.stripe_version;
   const uid = context.auth.uid;

     if (uid === null) {
     console.log('Illegal access attempt due to unauthenticated attempt.')
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Illegal access attempt');
    }

    return stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
     { customer: customerId },
     { stripe_version: stripeVersion }
   ).then((key) => {
   return key
   }).catch( (err) => {
    functions.logger.log('Error creating ephemeral key', err)
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Unable to create ephemeral key: ' + err)
    })
 })

   exports.createPaymentIntent = functions.https.onCall( async (data, context) => {

   const total = data.total
   const idempotency = data.idempotency
   const customer = context.auth.uid

   const uid = context.auth.uid;

    if (uid === null) {
     console.log('Illegal access attempt due to unauthenticated attempt.')
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Illegal access attempt');
    }

  return stripe.paymentIntents.create(
    {
    amount: total,
    currency: 'usd',
     customer: customer,
     payment_method_types: ['card', 'ach_debit']
      },
     {
     idempotencyKey: idempotency
   }
  ).then( intent => {
 return intent.client_secret
  }).catch( err => {
   functions.logger.log('Unable to create Stripe Payment Intent.')
    return null
    })
  })


  exports.fetchBankSources = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

   const customerId = data.customer_id

   const bankAccounts = await stripe.customers.listSources(
    customerId,
     { object: 'bank_account'}
     )

    return { banks: bankAccounts.data }
   })

   exports.deleteSource = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

   const customerId = data.customer_id
  const source = data.source

   return stripe.customers.deleteSource(customerId, source)
    .then(res => {
      return {
        status: 200
        }
     })
     .catch(err => {
      functions.logger.log(err)
           throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Unable to delete bank source: ' + err)
     })
   })
```

This is my SignUpViewController (The signed-up user shows on the Firenase-Auth Console as shown below --

[image]

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import Stripe

   class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var passwordConfirm: UITextField!
   @IBAction func signUpAction(_ sender: Any) {
     if password.text != passwordConfirm.text {let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Password Incorrect", message: "Please re-type password", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
           
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
   self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }else{
  Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email.text!, password: password.text!){ (user, error) in if error == nil {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signupToHome", sender: self)
    
                }
   else{
   let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
   let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                   
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

This is my "UserIdtoFirestoreViewController" which transfers my Auth email id. to Firestore as shown below:-

[image]

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore
class UserIdtoFirestoreViewController: UIViewController {
let db = Firestore.firestore()
var ref: DocumentReference? = nil
let email = Auth.auth().currentUser!.email
let id = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
let fullName = Auth.auth().currentUser!.displayName

 @IBAction func GetUserId(_ sender: UIButton) {
    db
        .collection("users")
        .document(id)
        .setData([
               "email":email,"price":2,"quantity":5 ])

      }
     }
```

Now, why does not the email show on the Stripe Dashboard ?

Comment: Where on the dashboard is the UID meant to be shown? May we see the Stripe Dashboard (and possibly the code used to display the page)?

Comment: Are you sure your `createStripeUser` firebase function is ever being called? Try adding logging to your function to confirm that it's actually being hit.